# How do I remove margin on the last element of a row

Tags: html, css

I have elements with the width 10px or 25px. These elements are all spaced by 5px. I need to fit these in a 55px box.

```
<style>
    .container{
        width: 55px;
    }
    .my_inner{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .w10{width: 10px;}
    .w25{width: 25px;}
</style>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO1
    </div><div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO2
    </div><div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO3
    </div><div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO4
    </div><div class='my_inner w25'>
        BAR1
    </div><div class='my_inner w25'>
        BAR2
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I do not know how many elements (w10 or w25) I will have and I do not know the order of them.

Naturally I would like to get FOO1 to FOO4 on the same *row* and BAR1 and BAR2 on the next row. But since the margin is included in the calculation FOO4 will not fit since all 4 elements are 4*(10+5)=60px wide.

I can not use the selector `:last` or `:last-child` since I do not know which element will be the last on each row.

I should be able to stack 2, 3  or 4 elements on one row (w25+w25, w10+w10+w25 or w25+w25).

Comment: I have added a javascript solution as it cannot be done with only CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with CSS.

You need to use javascript (*i prefer jQuery for ease of use*) to identify where the lines break (*since it is arbitrary*)

I have adjusted my solution to [Determine wrap location in floated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401024/determine-wrap-location-in-floated-elements/11401238#11401238) (*about fixed sized elements, but resizable container*)

```js
var wrapper = $('.container'),
    boxes = wrapper.children(),
    margin = parseInt(boxes.first().css('margin-right'),10);

$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = wrapper.width(),
        breaks = [],
        sofar = 0;
    
    boxes.removeClass('edge');
    
    boxes.each(function(i,e){
        var width = $(e).outerWidth(true);
        if ( (sofar + width <= w)){
            sofar += width;
        } else {
            if (sofar + width - margin <= w){
                breaks.push(i);
                sofar = 0;
            } else {
                breaks.push(i-1);
                sofar = width;
            }
        }
    });
    
    boxes
        .filter(function(i){
            return breaks.indexOf(i) > -1;
        })
        .addClass('edge');
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
.container{
    width: 55px;
}
.my_inner{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.w10{width: 10px;background-color:lightblue;}
.w25{width: 25px;background-color:lightgreen;}

.edge{margin-right:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO1
    </div><div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO2
    </div><div class='my_inner w25'>
        FOO3
    </div><div class='my_inner w10'>
        FOO4
    </div><div class='my_inner w25'>
        BAR1
    </div><div class='my_inner w25'>
        BAR2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got the question right an have a good answer! But after some fiddling on my own I think you can actually use css. `.container{margin-right: -5px;}`. Any drawbacks with that?

Comment: @UlfR it will create problems if other elements are to be put to its right. It will pull those in.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a class using jQuery.  By then your page would have loaded and the last child would have been defined.

http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Answer (score -1):

Go the other way around and set a different style for the first child.

```
.my_inner{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.my_inner:first-child{
    margin: 0;
}
```

`:first-child` is more supported than `:last-child`.

For IE8 support you must use HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: But this will give me the same issue as in my provided example except that the issue is there on all but the first row instead of all rows!