# calculate element width based on first line of children

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6d3bctex/1/)

This is supposed to be a responsive grid of images and for the last element on a line, the class `.last` is added by jQuery so it has no `margin-right`. (solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781759/how-do-i-remove-margin-on-the-last-element-of-a-row))

But now, I need to assign width to the `<section class="grid">` based on the width of the first line of elements for `margin: 0 auto` to work.

I tried this:

```
var width = 0;
$('section.grid img').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('.grid').css('width', width);
```

but obviously that doesn't work as it sums all the elements, not just the first line. Also the number of images on a line is variable based on the screen width.

Thank you.

Comment: first you can use the `:last-of-type` css selector to address the last image in your list, you don't need jquery for that. then there is `flexbox`, you can use it to create image grids (e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/using-modern-css-to-build-a-responsive-image-grid/). it's better if your layout doesn't depend on javascript (aka [progressive enhancement](http://alistapart.com/article/understandingprogressiveenhancement))

Comment: but the img elements aren't :last-of-type, they are just last before a line break

Comment: Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/6d3bctex/4/

Comment: @J.Soukup you are right, you would need to use `:nth-of-type()`. see this codepen for an easy example using flexbox: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Kgofa/left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Get the width of `window` and outerWidth(width + padding + margin) of `img`
2. Calculate the no of `img` that can fit into the window.
3. Apply the calculated width (no of `img`'s that can fit * it's width )

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/6d3bctex/4/)

Width for `<section class="grid">` can be calculated by `parseInt(winWidth / width) * width`

Comment: this does work, although you have to add -5 to `(winWidth / width) * width` to take into account the removed `margin-right: 5px`
thank you